# How do I import data from Excel that does not have a primary key in to a database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I am trying to import information from an excel sheet. The excel sheet changes as I get new information. Basically I am creating an excel sheet and saving it in to a city folder. The excel sheets do not have id #s in the columns and they dont need them. The columns are Business Name, Doing Business As, State, and City. My database has PK= ID, BusinessName,DoingBusinessAs,State,and City.

The problem Im having is the excel does not have an id number column. And since I have multiple excel sheets that I have to take care of from different locations, I cant have the id numbers or they will cause more havoc if I try to merge them. Basically Im creating a DNC list.

My code looks like

```
     private void butAddDnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        ofd.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = 
        ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

        DataClasses1DataContext conn = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                TableDNC addtable = new TableDNC()
                {
                    CompanyName = Convert.ToString(dr[0]),
                    DoingBusinessAs = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                    State = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
                    City = Convert.ToString(dr[3])
```

I am getting the error at the last part because it is searching for the id column. Ho do I add the columns and have the PK auto add the id number?

Comment: Define your ID field on the database table as AUTOINCREMENT and forget to set the number. The database engine will do it for you

Comment: I have done that, but I am getting an error. As it is written, it wants to place CompanyName in ID coloumn. If I start at 1 and go to 4, it cant find column 4 in the excel.

Comment: I keep getting this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
Additional information: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.

The program '[14448] CityBusinessPlanner.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).